# LifecycleHook: OnChanges - trigger without @input

Tags: angular, typescript

I've tried out the Lifecycle Hook OnChanges see https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks#onchanges

> Respond when Angular (re)sets data-bound input properties

My question now: Is it possible to trigger it on non-input properties which change their value in the html?
Why isn't it working like the following?

**I have those files:**
Html

```
<html>
  <input ([ngModel])="power"></input>
  <OnChangesTestComponent [power]="power"></OnChangesTestComponent>
</html>
```

HtmlComponent:

```
export class HtmlComponent implements {
  power: string;
  @ViewChild(OnChangesComponent) childView: OnChangesComponent;
}
```

OnChangesTestComponent:

```
export class OnChangesTestComponent implements OnChanges {
  @Input() power: string;

  ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
    ...
  }
}
```

**which i want to sum up in:**
Html

```
<html>
  <input ([ngModel])="power"></input>
</html>
```

HtmlComponent

```
export class HtmlComponent implements OnChanges {
  power: string;

  ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
    ...
  }
}
```

Comment: you need `doCheck` for general dirty check, `onChanges` is just for input changes

Comment: Be careful using `doCheck` @ABOS. I would recomend using it as last resource. `While the ngDoCheck() hook can detect when the hero's name has changed, it has a frightful cost` https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks#docheck

Comment: @ABOS Well tried to avoid using doCheck since it's called even if there was no change..

Comment: @LeandroLima, I don't think performance is an issue. normally, you check the changes  which is a simple if(.....) , i don't think calling this is costly in general